# Unity3D - Making an object follow the other with the same velocity (variable speed)

Tags: unity-game-engine, position, velocity

I have two circles in the same scene, and I need one of them repeat the same motion that other place. Only keeping the distance from the size of the other.

Considering circle "A" and circle "B", I'm storing the circle coordinate "A" on an array of positions, then the circle "B" reads these positions and performs.

With this methodology I face problems when increasing the speed circle "A", because as the circle "B" still reading the array the speed that was previously stored, making circles to separate.

**See the image:**

[image]

Ideally, the circle "B" run on the current speed of the circle "A", but it will never be possible to be reading from an array already recorded with the speed of circle "A" at that time.

```
    var dir = Input.mousePosition - Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
    var angle = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, dir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward), 180 * Time.deltaTime);
    transform.position += transform.right * Time.deltaTime * velocity;

    Camera.main.transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, Camera.main.transform.position.z);

    recordList.Insert(0, new Recorder
    {
      Position = transform.position,
      Rotation = transform.rotation,
      Velocity = velocity
    });
```

What would be the best way to make this scenario?

I appreciate any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to use the array of positions from "A" to create a route that the object "B" can interpret to calculate its position based on a fixed distance, not in a fixed time.

Thus the "A" object in its path would create a set of waypoints such A1, A2, A3, A4 ....

The B object must add distances between the lasts waypoints, until a "equal or greater" distance than the fixed distance A <-> B.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. But when we store the object in the array, the calculation is performed is stored at that time ... including the execution SPEED (which is calculated at the time that is stored) ` transform.position += transform.right * Time.deltaTime * velocity;´. Please see the updated question.